# Benford's Law and Uniform Distributions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

Here is a claim that I have a hard time understanding/proving:

"Because 2 is not a rational power of 10, the sequence $\{y_{n}\} =\{\log_{10}(2^n) mod1\}$ is uniformly distributed on [0,1)"

First of all what does $\log_{10}(2^n) mod1$ mean? Isn't anything mod 1 equal to 0? Second  why is this uniform?

Also is this related to my following observation:

Consider a sequence of powers of 2, and write each element in this sequence in scientific notation $x_m \times 10^{n_m}$. Then create a second sequence of first significant digits of $x_m$ (denote as $d_m$). Define $y_m = \log_{10}(x_m)$ and consider it in the interval $x \in [0,1)$. Is this $y_m$ same as the sequence of $\{\log_{10}(2^n) mod1\}$? If I assume its uniform, then the probability distribution follows simply:

$P(d) = Prob(d\le x < d+1) = Prob(\log_{10}(d) \le y < \log_{10}(d+1)) = \int_{\log_{10}(d)}^{\log_{10}(d+1)}1\,dy = \log_{10}(\frac{d+1}{d})$. Hence $P(d) = \log_{10}(\frac{d+1}{d})$

**Update: I figured it out!! Thanks to everyone who helped**

Comment: $\mod 1$ is just another word for 'fractional part'. So $n\mod 1=0$ for any integer, but $1.3892\mod 1=0.3892.$ This is just a matter of terminology. 

Proving that $(\log_{10}2^n\mod 1)_{n\ge 0}$ is uniform in $[0, 1)$ is, I think, non-trivial. It might be helpful to look at Weyl's equidistribution distribution.

Comment: Yes! As you mentioned $(\log_{10}x_m)\mod 1=(\log_{10}2^m)\mod 1.$